# How to get UPD packet when application is in background

Tags: ios, udp, asyncsocket, udpclient

I am new in iOS and now i got stuck so i thought i should post some thing over her may be some one help me out

i am developing iOS app and my app is able to send udp packet over local network every thing is working fine application can send and receive data packets.

my logic is listener open his socket and sender send the data packets on listener socket so its work fine but problem occur when lister after opening the port, application goes in background, its will not recive any packet until it become foreground again.

i am using asyncsocket his third part library and this function is call when udp receive msg

(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
}

but when application is in background this function not called its call when application become active,

so plz give me a solution application can receive udp packet until its on background

thanks in advance